# How to process RxJS stream n items at a time and once an item is done, autofill back to n again?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, backpressure

I have a stream of events and I would like to call a function that returns a promise for each of those events, the problem is that this function is very expensive, so I would like to process at most n events at a time.

This pebble diagram is probably wrong but this is what I would like:

```
---x--x--xxxxxxx-------------x------------->  //Events
---p--p--pppp------p-p-p-----p------------->  //In Progress
-------d--d--------d-d-dd------dddd-------->  //Promise Done

---1--21-2-34-----------3----4-3210--------   //QUEUE SIZE CHANGES
```

This is the code that I have so far:

```
var n = 4;
var inProgressCount = 0;

var events$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(produceEvent, 'click')
  .map((ev) => new Date().getTime());

var inProgress$ = events$.controlled();

var done$ = inProgress$      
  .tap(() => inProgressCount++)
  .flatMap((timestamp) => Rx.Observable.fromPromise(expensiveComputation(getRandomInt(1, 5) * 1000, timestamp)));

done$.subscribeOnNext((timestamp) => {
  inProgressCount--;
  inProgress$.request(Math.max(1, n - inProgressCount));
});

inProgress$.request(n);
```

There are two issues with this code:

1. It's using the `inProgressCount` var which is updated with side
   effect functions.
2. <s>The done$ subscription is only called once when I request more than 1 item from the controlled stream. This is making the `inProgressCount` var to update incorrectly, this eventually limits the queue to one at a time.</s>

You can see it working in here:
http://jsbin.com/wivehonifi/1/edit?js,console,output

Questions:

1. Is there a better approach?
2. How can I get rid of the `inProgressCount` variable?
3. <s>Why is the done$ subscription only getting called once when requesting multiple items?</s>

Update:

Answer to question #3: switchMap is the same as flatMapLatest, so that's why I was only getting the last one. Updated the code to flatMap instead of switchMap.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You actually don't need to use backpressure at all. There is an operator called `flatMapWithMaxConcurrent` that does this for you. It is essentially an alias for calling `.map().merge(concurrency)` and it only allows a maximum number of streams to be in flight at a time.

I updated your jsbin here: http://jsbin.com/weheyuceke/1/edit?js,output

But I annotated the important bit below:

```
const concurrency = 4;

var done$ = events$
  //Only allows a maximum number of items to be subscribed to at a time
  .flatMapWithMaxConcurrent(concurrency, 
    ({timestamp}) =>   
      //This overload of `fromPromise` defers the execution of the lambda
      //until subscription                    
      Rx.Observable.fromPromise(() => { 
        //Notify the ui that this task is in progress                                 
        updatePanelAppend(inProgress, timestamp);
        removeFromPanel(pending, timestamp);
        //return the task
        return expensiveComputation(getRandomInt(1, 5) * 1000, timestamp)
     }));
```

Comment: In RxJs 5 you must replace .flatMapWithMaxConcurrent with .mergeMap(mapper, (resultSelectorFunction | null), concurrency) [mergeMap](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-mergeMap)